# Route VPN traffic to internal VPN server on SOnicwall NSA220

Tags: vpn, sonicwall

We have a Sonicwall NSA220 firewall, and about 4 public IPs we can use.

I have just set up a Windows 2012 VPN server internally and will ask our DNS hosts to route VPN.domainname.com to one of the free IPs.
Our firewall typically already has a public IP assigned to it, which is also the default WAN.

My question is, if I use one of the unallocated public IPs allocated to us for the VPN connection, will it have to have another interface allocated to it on the Sonicwall, or is there a way I can use the existing WAN connection?

The ISPs Cisco router should forward the traffic for all those IPs to our firewall anyway.

Thanks,
Evren

Answer (score 0):

Its not that intuitive on the NSA devices and took me a while to work out how to use additional IPs but basically if you have your WAN interface (X1) set up with the correct subnet then you can just use any of the IPs in the range.

Simplest way to publish is to just click on the "Wizard" link in the top right and follow the instructions and when it asks for the public IP just give it a new one